# Keep JavaScript injection despite of refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, jdeveloper

I want to inject some JavaScript code that loads a new page and then executes a function. But when it loads the page, it doesn't execute the rest of the code. I have seen on the internet, that when a new page is loaded or refreshed the JavaScript console is cleared. I have tried with a Chrome extension that injects the JavaScript code, and it doesn't work neither.
What can I do? Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var button = document.getElementById('skip_bu2tton'); // ID of the button
    setTimeout(function(){
        button.click();
        alert("OK");
    },12000);
window.open("**URL**","_self"); // URL opened in the same tab
```

There is some way to make the Chrome Extension Injector to make this automaticaly, so it must open the URL, wait a few seconds, click that button and repeat that process over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I think chrome local overrides might be just what you are looking for.
Here's the info how to use it: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides